# How to a make a loop in java that will print a slightly different string on each line?

Tags: java, loops

For my first computer science class, I am trying to make a program that prints an ASCII design of the Canadian flag. I already have a program that works, but it is bulky, and I was hoping to simplify it. Is there a way to make a loop print the same output?

```
    public class Flag{
/* 
    * Uses fixed combinations of ASCII characters to produce 
    * the Canadian flag.
*/
    public static void main(String args[]){

    //Components of flag
    String topAndBottom ="|---------------------------------------|";
    String leftSide = "|**********";
    String rightSide = "**********|";
    String flagRow1 ="                   ";
    String flagRow2 ="         ^         ";
    String flagRow3 ="      ^ /*\\ ^      ";
    String flagRow4 ="     /*\\|*|/*\\     ";
    String flagRow5 =" . --*********-- . ";
    String flagRow6 ="    \\*********/    ";
    String flagRow7 ="     >*******<     ";
    String flagRow8 ="    ***********    ";
    String flagRow9 ="     ---------     ";
    String flagRow10 ="        | |        ";

    //Print flag
    System.out.println(" "+"\n"+
    topAndBottom+"\n"+
    leftSide+flagRow1+rightSide+"\n"+
    leftSide+flagRow2+rightSide+"\n"+
    leftSide+flagRow3+rightSide+"\n"+
    leftSide+flagRow4+rightSide+"\n"+
    leftSide+flagRow5+rightSide+"\n"+
    leftSide+flagRow6+rightSide+"\n"+
    leftSide+flagRow7+rightSide+"\n"+
    leftSide+flagRow8+rightSide+"\n"+
    leftSide+flagRow9+rightSide+"\n"+
    leftSide+flagRow10+rightSide+"\n"+
    leftSide+flagRow1+rightSide+"\n"+
    topAndBottom+"\n");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You might want to check [Code Review subsite](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) which is more suitable for code improvement suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an *array*. And, in Java 8+, a `Stream` like

```
// Components of flag
String topAndBottom = "|---------------------------------------|";
String leftSide = "|**********";
String rightSide = "**********|";
String[] rows = { "                   ", //
        "         ^         ", //
        "      ^ /*\\ ^      ", //
        "     /*\\|*|/*\\     ", //
        " . --*********-- . ", //
        "    \\*********/    ", //
        "     >*******<     ", //
        "    ***********    ", //
        "     ---------     ", //
        "        | |        ", //
        "                   " };
System.out.println(topAndBottom);
Stream.of(rows).forEachOrdered(r -> System.out.println(leftSide + r + rightSide));
System.out.println(topAndBottom);
```

Comment: Why bother with the stream?  What's wrong with a good old for-each loop?